# How to add the class to the loop?

Tags: jquery

I have got a HTML as shown below

```
<div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="4">
   <section id="topping_tsection_4">
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      2</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_ZZ_1_ZZ_0"  qt_val="4_ZZ_1_ZZ_0">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      3</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_ZZ_2_ZZ_0"  qt_val="4_ZZ_2_ZZ_0">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
   </section>
</div>
```

I have got a value as 2

```
var value = 2;
```

How can i add  the  class="tpActive" for the first two anchor tags  ??

so that it looks

```
<a data-id="4" topping_id="1" class="tpActive"  id="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.Topping-details').find('.secclass a:lt(2)').addClass('tpActive');
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/xcnh30zL/

Answer (score 0):

One way to add this is:

```
$("#4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0").addClass("tpActive");  // add class to first anchor tag
$("#4_ZZ_1_ZZ_0").addClass("tpActive");  // add class to second anchor tag
```

**EDIT:** A better way of doing this is by using multiple selectors in the same line:

```
$("#4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0, #4_ZZ_1_ZZ_0").addClass("tpActive");  // add class to both anchor tags at once
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var value = 2;
 $("#4 .secclass a:lt("+value +")").addClass("tpActive");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mw5sgcLn/8/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 2;
var flag = 0;
$('a').each(function(){
  if(flag < value)
    $(this).attr('class','tpActive') //OR  $(this).addClass('tpActive')
    flag = flag + 1;
});
```

**EDIT :-**

DEMO :- http://jsfiddle.net/n6wj5z7m/

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 2;
$("div.Topping-details a").each(function(index, value){
    if(index < value){
      $(value).addClass("tpActive");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC Razor view you can use like this-

```
 class="@if(value==2){<text>tpActive</text>}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Topping-details a:lt(2)').addClass('tpActive');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery have a function addClass() and removeClass().

```
$("#4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0").addClass("tpActive");
```

Or you can try

```
$("img").attr("width","500");
```